# Consumer not tiggering even after solving exception in consumer, its tiggering after backofftime

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have implemented consumer retry for exception/failure.
Consumer not triggering until backoff time without exception.
I have two questions here

1. Consumer triggered very first within milliseconds, when exception occurred it retrying after (10 min) backoff time. **after resolving the exception case**. the failed consumer triggering and successfully completing. After this i am producing new data to topic and consumer triggering but it is triggering after 10 min. the exception case already resolved still why it is running after 10 min i am not getting any thing wrong i did?.

   ```
    org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new 
   RetryTemplate();

     RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(10);
     FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
     backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000);

     retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
     retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

     retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
       try {
         //call to service here exception comes
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
         throw new IllegalStateException(..);
      }
     });

    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.maxAttempts=3
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.backOffInitialInterval=600000
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.backOffMaxInterval=600000
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.backoffMultiplier=1.0
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.defaultRetryable=false

    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.enableDlq=true
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.dlqName=dlq-topic
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.in.0.consumer.dlqPartitions=1
   ```
2. In continuous process of above. After consumer failing it retying for every 10 mins for 3 times. after resolving exception. it retrying same now as i resolved the exception it should pass and **retry should not happen again**. it retrying for how times it failed previously.

Comment: Can you please provide a small sample and push it t Github so we can take a look. Also for your case you don't need to implement custom RetryTemplate, hence I want to look at the example. It seems like something  else is wring in your app

Comment: ok I will push.

Comment: hey @OlegZhurakousky, I was away, this is the git hub link, https://github.com/vshivaku/kafka-sample/tree/main/demo  please check i just created it now to share

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky i have added in repo only the code related to kafka. Hope this is enough, if anything required i will share.

Comment: any suggestion please?

Comment: Why are you creating your own instance of the retry temple inside of your consumer and expect your configuration properties to affect it? The configuration properties for retry assume you are using framework provided instance. You consumer should have nothing but the business code and if it fails the retry will happen. So Ia m not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but i suggest read https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling which also covers  RetryTemplate configuration